# column header text changes after change DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I change DataSource of my DataGridView with DataTable who don't have rows, and after that change DataSource with DataTable who contains rows, header text changes and another properties like width...

Comment: yes it will change depending on the columns of the datatable

Comment: are you trying to populate the gridview with rows but not change the column headers?

Comment: DataTable have always same columns. When table don't have rows problem starts.
I refresh table with this code:
dgvPrivateVehicle.DataSource = dt.Select("tip_p_s='private'").Length > 0 ? dt.Select("tip_p_s='private'").CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();

Comment: in previous comment didn't write that new DataTable() was defined before that code with same columns. In previous code new DataTable() I used to make a example.

Comment: more code please. I guess some down-voter will jump in here and does his favorite job.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `BindingSource` control between the `DataGridView` and the `DataTable`. The `BindingSource` control has a very useful property called `Filter` that will filter out unwanted rows without creating a new `DataTable` object or otherwise affecting the structure of the underlying `DataTable`, thus your DataGridView's headers will not be affected.

You can either do this manually through code or drop an instance of the BindingSource in the designer. The code would look something like this:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = YourDataTable;
YourGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

Then you can filter out your results by simply doing:

```
bs.Filter = "some_column = 'some_value'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your DGV first before re-populating it with a DataTable that has rows.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by making copy of DT and clearing rows from her. Than I assign that DT to DataSorce and now all works fine. Maybe not best way but it works. Thank you all!